# I'm not using Express, but I'm trying extract POST data then to send a json as response, with no luck

Tags: json, node.js

I'm still very new to node.js so please bear with me.

I'm trying to extract POST data then sent a json as response, but I don't seem to be able to extract the data from the POST request and even worse I can't find the syntax for people who are NOT using Express to send the json. It keeps telling me res.json is not a function.

EDIT: I found out the problem for the json part, I was a dump. I finally remember what I was told, json are sent like strings.

```
var http = require('http');
var qs = require("querystring");

server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    try {
        var body = "";
        var post = qs.parse("");
        if (req.method == "POST") {
        res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
        req.on("data", function (data) {
        body += data;
        console.log(data); //It gives something like <Buffer xx xx xx ...>
        if (body.length > 1e6)
            req.connection.destroy();
        });
    req.on("end", function () {
        post = qs.parse(body);
        console.log(post.test); //It gives "undefined"
    });
    res.end(JSON.stringify({ a: 1 }));
    } catch(err) {
        console.dir(err);
        res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        res.end("Hi hi");
    }
});

server.listen(8000);
console.log("http start @8000");
```

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is qs ....?

Comment: so you're parsing the post request as a stream (hence you get a buffer), you need to first convert the chunk to string (such that body will be parsed).

Comment: @ZeRubeus qs is queryString. Thanks for reminding, I just added that bit in the code.

Comment: @DenisTsoi Ok... But how? To be very honest I'm not even sure how does the codes work for that part. I tried to follow some other question's answer to grab the data.

Comment: check the answer below (`response` is a readableStream, i.e. Buffer - you need to convert the stream into human readable text, i.e. toString in order to read the data.

please check the answer below for implementation to reading the POST data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below solves the date to string (i.e. converting buffer to string

```
res.on('data', function(chunk) {  
    var textChunk = chunk.toString('utf8');  
    // console.log(textChunk); // will give you a stream of text from data
});
```

you could store textChunk out of the `ondata` handler, to then use that if required (say returning relevant data to the user back again)

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!
Though there's something I'd like you to know, it didn't work in `res.on` but rather in `req.on`. I put `body` into the `chunk` part and then it worked like intended.

Comment: thanks - appreciate the upvote and verified answer :D